# How to customize Bootbox.js prompt options

Tags: bootbox

I am trying to customize bootboxjs.prompt options, but it seems that it doesn't allow an options object as a parameter

This is the example from http://bootboxjs.com/index.html#api

```
bootbox.prompt("What is your name?", function(result) {                
  if (result === null) {                                             
    Example.show("Prompt dismissed");                              
  } else {
    Example.show("Hi <b>"+result+"</b>");                          
  }
});
```

This is what I am trying to pass:

```
var promptOptions = {
  title: "Custom label",
  buttons: {
    confirm: {
      label: "Save"
    }
  }
};

bootbox.prompt(promptOptions, function(result) {                
  if (result === null) {                                             
    console.log("Prompt dismissed");                              
  } else {
    console.log("Hi "+result);                          
  }
});
```

How can I customize the title and buttons label ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You will be able to make a custom prompt using custom dialogs.
The only thing you have to know is that the message string you give to bootbox doesn't have to be plain text. It can be HTML, so you can put your own prompt in a custom bootbox dialog.

What you are trying to do is this (using Bootbox 4.x):

```
bootbox.dialog({
  message: "First name:<input type='text' id='first_name'>",
  title: "Custom label",
  buttons: {
    main: {
      label: "Save",
      className: "btn-primary",
      callback: function() {
        console.log("Hi "+ $('#first_name').val());
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: is there any I can use javascript in the message ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489040/how-to-select-images-from-a-dialog-and-embed-in-the-textarea this is my question if you can help me out ?

Comment: is there way `ok` or `save` button remain disabled if input nothing

Answer (score 21):

`bootbox.prompt` only takes one parameter if you want to pass an object with your custom labels. So in order to make it work, you have to put your callback in your config object:

```
var promptOptions = {
  title: "Custom label",
  buttons: {
    confirm: {
      label: "Save"
    }
  },
  callback: function(result) {                
      if (result === null) {                                             
        console.log("Prompt dismissed");                              
      } else {
        console.log("Hi "+result);                          
      }
    }
};

bootbox.prompt(promptOptions);
```

Comment: I agree with @mseo. This is the best way to use prompt correctly. check this : https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/issues/143 (for the future visitors)

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that you need to use `.dialog` if you want to add the `message` option.

Comment: @TedAvery no, `prompt` supports the `message` option. Check the latest docs: http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-dialog-options

Comment: The message option isn't working for me either, but the documentation says it does? Weird.

Comment: The message option was not working for me using the prompt() method on an older version of Bootbox, but I can confirm that is working as per the latest version (6.x).